# Loading javascript libraries included in an appended SVG file

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to build a browser-based SVG rasterizer. The SVG files can contain javascript code that affects the output (for example, randomly changes colors of elements) and use libraries (for example [chroma.js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/)) to do that.

The process I am trying to implement is:

1. load the SVG file
2. load libraries linked in the SVG file
3. execute the javascript included inside script tags
4. display on a canvas
5. save the canvas as PNG

This is necessary because appending the SVG to the HTML element does not run the JS included inside SVG.

Everything works well - except the loading of external libraries (point 2). The snippet that does that is as follows

```
$.get('/some_svg_file.svg', function(d) {
      // this will be replaced with file drag/drop later
      var getLibs = Array.from(d.querySelectorAll('script'))
        .filter(p => p.getAttribute('xlink:href'))
        .map(p => {
          return axios.get(p.getAttribute('xlink:href'))
        })

      // only run embedded js after libraries have been downloaded
      Promise.all(getLibs).then((values) => {
            values.forEach(d => {
              try {
                eval(d.data);
              } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
              }
            });

            Array.from(d.querySelectorAll('script'))
              .forEach(p => {
                if (p.textContent.length) {
                  try {
                    eval(p.textContent)
                  } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                  }
                }
              })
           // code that writes to canvas etc goes here
     })
})
```

So, if I put link chroma.js in the html file header, everything works ok. If I download it and `eval` it, the scripts inside the SVG file fail with `ReferenceError: chroma is not defined`

Another attempt I did was using the script tag technique like so:

```
$.get('/foo_with_js.svg', function(d) {
      var getLibs = Array.from(d.querySelectorAll('script'))
        .filter(p => p.getAttribute('xlink:href'))
        .map(p => {
          var s = document.createElement('script');
          s.src = p.getAttribute('xlink:href');
          s.type = "text/javascript";
          s.async = false;
          document.querySelector('head').appendChild(s);
        })
   // load scripts and save to canvas
})
```

which also failed in the same way (despite chroma.js being neatly included in the head section.

So how could I get this to work - so that I can load SVG, append it to HTML and run the scripts inside it without having to pre-link all the possible scripts in the HTML?

Ah - and if you're asking why not use some other conversion process, the answer is "lack of consistent support for SVG filters"

Comment: If you are loading arbitrary svg files of which you don't know the possible javascript libraries it would include then I can not imagine any solution. I have widely used libraries with svg but calling them from html and embedding the svg withing the html code. Svg also supports javascript embedded into its code but always embedding the svg inside the html. I really don't know if rendering a single svg file in the browser will execute the js without the html support.

Comment: Actually that’s what I am trying  to do - figure out how to run the libraries included in the SVG in the HTML _too_

Comment: You should call the svg into the html using the object tag. This way you could create a script which scans the svg in search for js libraries links and execute them from the html. No idea on how to do this but as a logic to follow it is valid

Comment: Can you add a simple SVG document example (including the reference to the script). Question: Is the SVG document functional if it is just displayed independent in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you can make this work with *any* JavaScript library embedded in SVG is a good question, but here I have an example where I use [chroma.js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/) like you suggested.

A reference to the SVG document is added to the data attribute of `<object>`. Here it is static, but I guess it could be dynamically updated. Now the SVG is doing its thing, like setting a color on the `<rect>` and animating the cy attribute of the `<circle>`. At any point I can grab the contentDocument (contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML) of `<object>`, that is the SVG document at a particular point. If values in the document is changing this will affect the contentDocument. Now I can take the string (outerHTML) and turn that into a data URI. The data URI can be set as src on an image object and the image can be rendered in the `<canvas>` element. In the outerHTML you can see that there are also references to the JavaScript library and the JavaScript code that I wrote, but this is not executed in the image when rendered into `<canvas>`.

SVG document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="drop-shadow">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
            <feoffset in="blur" dx="4" dy="4" result="offsetBlur"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="offsetBlur"/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <script href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chroma-js/2.1.2/chroma.min.js"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="20" fill="blue" style="filter: url(#drop-shadow);"/>
    <script>
        // <![CDATA[
        var cy = 40;
        var speed = 5;
        document.querySelector('rect').style.fill = chroma('hotpink');
        setInterval(function(){
            if(cy > 160 || cy < 40) speed *= -1;
            cy += speed;
            document.querySelector('circle').attributes['cy'].value = cy;
        }, 500);
        // ]]>
    </script>
</svg>
```

HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var object, canvas, img, loop;

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
                object = document.querySelector('object');
                canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
                img = new Image();

                img.addEventListener('load', e => {
                    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);
                });

                object.addEventListener('load', e => {
                    loop = setInterval(function(){
                        var svg64 = btoa(e.target.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML);
                        var b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
                        img.src = b64Start + svg64; 
                    }, 500);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object type="image/svg+xml" width="200" height="200" data="test.svg"></object>
        <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

These two documents need to run from a server, so **not** directly from the filesystem.

From what I have tested the [SVG animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) and [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) are not working in this setup. Only the "animations" in JavaScript where you manipulate the DOM is working.

Comment: @chrwal - it looks like a very interesting approach. I am in the middle of something else but I’ll check it out and feedback ASAP. Thanks in the meantime